# Is it beneficial to trade a skill for better saving throws for a spell-less Ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, optimization, saving-throw

I'm working on a new character, which will be a spell-less ranger. In this case, I'm multiclassing a Rogue / Ranger, with a preference for melee (over ranged).

For the sake of this question, assume the character to start at level 5.

The saving throws and number of skills are based on which class I start as at first level:

- Start as a **Ranger** Saving throws: Str & Dex, 4 skills,
- Start as a **Rogue** Saving throws: Dex & Int, 5 skills.

So, I can basically trade 1 skill to switch a Str saving throw for an Int saving throw.

**Is the Str saving throw instead of an Int saving throw *objectively* more valuable than an extra (a 5th) skill at 5th level in an average game?**

---

A spell-less ranger in this case will consist of a Ranger (Hunter/Beast master) - Rogue (Scout) multi-class character. The envisioned playstyle for this spell-less Ranger is as a Ranger: outdoor, sneaky, ambush, at home in nature, guide. But without the Ranger's magic abilities. The Rogue archetype 'Scout' was created for this role.
In my case, I would like to play the spell-less ranger as a melee-focused character.

Also, I'm new to D&D 5th edition, so I have no good idea on how common the various types of saving throws will come up, or what the impact of missing said saving throw would be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a spell-less Ranger? Are you not interested in the other differences between Ranger and Rogue?

Comment: @kviiri: A spell-less ranger did appear as an example in the [Modifying Classes UA](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/modifying-classes), though I don't know if that's what the asker means.

Comment: Depending on player's playestyle, any (or both) of them might be valuable; as it is now (without a context) question is *primarily opinion-based*.

Answer (score 2):

### They're incomparable

It's relatively easy to compare the strength of DnD features that have clearly defined mechanical uses. Most of the time, that means combat, where one is far more likely to use a Strength saving throw than most skills.

The problem with comparing a Strength save proficiency and an extra skill proficiency is that the role and impact of various skills is largely up to your GM. I've played in tables where only a few particular skills (Perception and Stealth) were used to effect often while the rest of the skills were used for flavor only, if at all, but also tables where skill rolls made a huge impact and were used often to resolve situations without combat. The difference is huge.

Without any context about what one can do with a skill, we have to settle on the answer that you can't really compare the two.

Comment: This trade also involves not getting Int saving throw proficiency.

Comment: @Miniman Aye, although the OP seems to be completely aware of that so I assume they find Str to be far prefarable over Int save proficiency.

Comment: I'm aware that the Str saving throw would replace the Int saving throw. I'm just not sure if the Str saving throw is more desirable than an Int saving throw.

Comment: @Monika Well, that changes the question quite dramatically, but I'm rather sure Int and Str saving throws can be compared against each other with some usefulness (eg. how commonly monster abilities use each)